# Ionic 2 project architecture (images)

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

In `Ionic 2` project, what is the right place to put my images?
In some blogs, people said to put all the images in `www\build\"images_folder"`,
but the problem is when you `build` the project or command: `ionic serve` your build folder is totally removed and rebuild from the start and you loose all your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `ionic serve` all the javascript and styles files are compiled and put together (among other tasks) in your `build` folder, and that's why if you put somethig there, is deleted.

In order to avoid that, you should put your images in `www\images` and then reference them in your code by doing:

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" />
```

======================

EDIT:

You can find more information about what's going on when you run `ionic serve` (and also `emulate`, `deploy` and `build`) by taking a look at your `gulpfile.js`:

```
/**
 * Ionic hooks
 * Add ':before' or ':after' to any Ionic project command name to run the specified
 * tasks before or after the command.
 */
gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch']);
gulp.task('emulate:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('deploy:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('build:before', ['build']);
```

And in the lasts lines of code of the gulpfile.js you can see this:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del('www/build');
});
```

Which is what causes the build folder to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My mistake was that I put the images under  /www/build/images and not www/images